# sending an array to graphQL endpoint

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

The graphQL server is set up. It works properly when the values are hardcoded. Here is my invocation request:

```
"query": "mutation{
    createEvent(name: "+ name +", purpose: "+ purpose +", googleUserName: "+ googleUserName +", dateArray: "+ JSON.stringify(dateArray) +", attendees: [])
    {
      eventId
      name
      purpose
      googleUserName 
      dateArray 
      attendees{
         attendeeName
         personalizedDateSelection
         }
      }
   }"
```

This gives the error:

```
{"errors":
   [{"message":
     "Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:88) Expected :, found Name \"dateArray\"\n\n1: mutation{createEvent(name: lakshman, purpose: test, googleUserName: Diwaakartg Ganesh, dateArray: [\"Wed, Nov 9th 2016\",\"Thu, Nov 10th 2016\",\"Thu, Nov 3rd 2016\",\"Wed, Nov 2nd 2016\"], attendees: [])
      {eventId
       name
       purpose
       googleUserName
       dateArray
       attendees{
          attendeeName 
          personalizedDateSelection
          }
       }
    }\n}]}
```

**There is no alignment error. I have made it so to enhance the readability**
But, the above mutation works properly when hardcoded the arguments. I find it pretty difficult to find what is the cause of the error. I have tried both **JSON.stringify(dateArray)** and just the **dateArray** alone.

Or is there a better approach to query GraphQL from react-redux app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to pass complex options, the best way to do that is to use [**variables**](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables). That way, you don't have to worry about formatting anything into the query string.

So you would send a request like this:

```
{
  "query": `
    mutation CreateEvent(
      $name: String!,
      $purpose: String!,
      $googleUserName: String!,
      $dateArray: [String],
      $attendees: [String]
    ) {
      createEvent(
        name: $name,
        purpose: $purpose,
        googleUserName: $googleUserName,
        dateArray: $dateArray,
        attendees: $attendees
      ) {
        eventId
        name
        purpose
        googleUserName 
        dateArray 
        attendees{
          attendeeName
          personalizedDateSelection
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  "variables": {
    "name": "...",
    "purpose": "...",
    "googleUserName": "...",
    "dateArray": [...],
    "attendees": []
  }
}
```

If you have worked with SQL before, it's the equivalent of using `?` in your query and passing the arguments separately. Basically, you shouldn't be manually serializing and concatenating the query in your app, because variables are designed specifically for that case.

In fact, there are a lot of great reasons to keep your queries as completely static strings, as we outlined in [this blog post](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/5-benefits-of-static-graphql-queries-b7fa90b0b69a#.mll8l2e9s).

Comment: !! Thanks for the example. But do I need to import some packages like [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-tag). The variables part is very cool though, could not find any online implementations. Would be helpful If you give me an elaborate instructions to use it in my app.

Comment: You don't need any packages, you can literally just send a POST request with the form I wrote.

Comment: It was my bad!! Ya worked like a charm!! When I was looking in the blog, there was things about apollo-client, relay and so on. In my perspective, since I use redux, I think I dont need to implement relay, but what about some graphql clients like apollo-client which claims to be efficient and helps in caching the query results and optimistic updates. @stubailo your thoughts ?

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers of Apollo :) I think it's a good way to use graphql with redux without worrying about writing actions and reducers yourself, but it's not totally necessary if you want to do it yourself.